# LocationMatch not working, is there a way to debug Apache?

Tags: apache

I have a server using Joomla on an AWS EC2, 64bit Amazon Linux v2.1.3, PHP 5.6, and we would like to prevent access to the /administrator folder php files, with the exception of our office ip, and the ip of the server, since the folder contains libraries used by scripts not located in that folder.

I put together the following using LocationMatch, but it is not working. Access to the server is not restricted.

I am not very familiar with Apache, and especially with SetEnvIf. Is the below setting the env=allow no matter what? Is there a way to test that? Is there anything else that is wrong?

```
<LocationMatch "/(administrator|tmpl)">
 SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.(css|js|html|htm|gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$" allow
 Deny from all
 ##except if either of these are satisfied
 Satisfy any
 ##1. a valid authenticated user
 Allow from ip1 ip2
 ## or 2. allow is set
 Allow from env=allow
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: What is the apache version?

Comment: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Satisfy` directive is only useful if access to a particular area is being restricted by **both** username/password and client host address: with the `Any` option the client will be granted access if they either pass the host restriction or enter a valid username and password. Since you don't have any user restrictions, with `Satisfy any` you are effectively granting access to everyone.

Since you are running 2.4, this should work:

```
<LocationMatch "/(administrator|tmpl)">
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.(css|js|html|htm|gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$" allow
    <RequireAny>
        Require env allow
        Require ip 10.0.2.2 10.0.2.3
    </RequireAny>
</LocationMatch>
```

If your server is behind ELB, the connection to Apache will come from load balancer and not directly from the client, so IP address can not be used in `Require ip`. But ELB adds several request headers in order to pass this information to the origin server, one of them being the `X-Forwarded-For` which will contain the IP address of the client. If the original request already contained this header (which is not unusual at all), ELB will append the client IP address to existing value(s) so you will get comma+space separated list of IP addresses. The last (rightmost) IP address is always the IP address that connects to the last proxy (your ELB), which means that is the one you want to test against, so try:

```
<LocationMatch "/(administrator|tmpl)">
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.(css|js|html|htm|gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$" allow
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For x.x.x.x$ office
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For y.y.y.y$ bar
    <RequireAny>
        Require env allow
        Require env office
        Require env bar
    </RequireAny>
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of RequireAny and certainly appears to be the best way to do this. php files are blocked from the allowed ip address, but .html files are allowed.  So I believe the "Require env allow" is working as expected, but the Require ip is not. When you list two ip addresses, does that act as a "or" or an "and"?  I looked but could not finnd the answer. if the answer is "and", then should I simply put the ip's on two lines?

Comment: I doubt it is "and", client can never have 2 IP addresses, it wouldn't make sense. Try to access, and then took at the apache error log for the something like `[client 10.0.2.2:52809] AH01630: client denied by server configuration:`, perhaps the client is not coming from the IP address you expect (there might be some proxies or load balancers in between)

Comment: 10.0.1.200 (50.myofficeip.0.0) - - [30/Dec/2016:16:57:15 +0000] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 403 223 "-" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"
10.0.1.200 (50.myofficeip.0.0) - - [30/Dec/2016:16:57:16 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1406 "http://www.ebclone.com/administrator/"
 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"

Comment: 2nd time - sorry - can you tell what ip it sees? - [Fri Dec 30 16:57:15.634738 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 5315] [client 10.0.1.200:46677] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/administrator/

Comment: So the client  address is `10.0.1.200`, is that what you have in `Require ip`?

Comment: No, I will try to figure out where that came from. If that is generic, than it will allow anyone to access, and defeat the purpose, correct? Is this something that needs to be done on the aws side to allow my ip to go around whatever is changing the ip?

Comment: Is there an AWS Elastic Load Balancer in front of this server?

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks so much, would have never been able to complete this without your help.